# Getting ruby constants in JS files on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have some constants defined in my Rails app that I want to use in my JS files.

To do this, I have `js.erb` files in my `assets/javascripts` directory, and insert those constants where needed in ERB blocks.

However, Heroku apparently doesn't load the app before precompiling the assets, so that approach isn't working.

How can I include my Ruby constants in my JS files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried compiling your assets locally before pushing to Heroku?

They have some docs on it here actually: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally